# 2k3 Server Not recognizing the correct network zones for one profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, zones

When I log on to this machine any browsing web or windows only recognises "My Computer" and "Internet", everything that is not on the local machine is "Internet".

A colleague logs on and the zone is shown correctly in the status bar.

My profile works on other machines fine

Attempts to fix have included:
   Deleting the profile from the machine
   Removing the server from the Domain, deleting the AD machine account, reconnect.

Other may be connected issues:
   Browsing to http://localhost - I get challenged for uname/pass. Still says "Internet" in the status bar. When I go to ADD the website to the Intranet Zone. I get a dialog that says "There was an unexpected error with your zone settings. Unable to add this site."

Answer (score 1):

Open IE, Tools, Options, Secuirty, set all zones to default.

check if another address has been assigned to a network interface which isn;t on you local network.